# Serverless wsgi application and aws http api fail to integrate

Tags: python, flask, aws-api-gateway, wsgi, serverless-framework

I have a serverless application and want to change the api gateway version to v2 (from [rest api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-rest-api.html) to [http api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api.html)). The serverless app works just fine with the rest api, and upgrading the api to http api is pretty easy and straight forward.
But when making an api call to the service with http api enabled, it always returns 500 status code for some reason. One thing I've found out is that when I change the [payload format version](http://%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-rest-api.html) to `'1.0'`, it works just fine.

I'm using `serverless-wsgi` plugin in order to run my flask app and suspecting it doesn't know how to use payload format version `'2.0'`, and wanted to verify it. Here is my `serverless.yml` file for clearer understanding:

```yaml
service: my-service-name

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  httpApi:
    # thats the trick that fixes my http api calls
    payload: '1.0'
    cors:
      allowedOrigins:
        - '*'
      allowedHeaders:
        - Content-Type
        - Authorization
      allowCredentials: false

functions:
  api:
    handler: wsgi_handler.handler
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: '*'

plugins:
  - serverless-wsgi

custom:
  wsgi:
    app: src/api.app
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have been using an older `serverless-wsgi` version. There has been an [update](https://github.com/logandk/serverless-wsgi/releases/tag/1.7.6) that supports v2 payload.